# My car vibrates on the bite point when no gas is given only at first gear (manual transmission)

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission

My car vibrates on the bite point when no gas is given only at first gear (manual transmission). When gas is given it works fine. IT IS A NEW CLUTCH.

Comment: Has one of the mountings been left loose or is damaged / broken?

Comment: Please go back and delete your "answer" to this question, as it is not an answer... https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/62649/10976

Comment: Welcome to the site, I'm afraid that might be considered off topic as it relates to driving technique.

Comment: @SolarMike I dont know for sure about the mountings, must be fine because car doesnt vibrate during running only at first gear...  I deleted it

Comment: @SteveMatthews I have drived and other cars but this look something different

Comment: @Teo I would not assume that they are "fine", had some that had gone "soft" and others that had split and were fine at speed... Personally, I would check them...

Comment: Did they machine surface or replace the flywheel? If neither this is the cause of vibration, putting a new clutch disc on a glazed flywheel.

Comment: @Moab I dont know for sure if they replaced the flywheel. Is it something to worry about, should it be replaced??

Comment: Most shops will have the flywheel machined to give it a new surface, this is common practice for competent shops.

Answer (score 2):

If your old clutch was replaced because it was worn out (or nearly worn out) then the new clutch is likely to be providing a significantly higher amount of friction at the biting point than the old one has for quite some time (similar to how new brakes will be able to stop the car much more sharply then heavily worn ones). The energy the engine is providing is insufficient to overcome this friction but it has to go *somewhere* - hence the vibration.

When you give it more throttle you are allowing the engine to overcome this friction (and the car then drives off).

So in other words (as Steve's excellent answer points out) this is normal behavior and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok I understand so the vibrate will dissapear over time?

Answer (score 0):

By not giving the car any throttle and with a fresh new clutch installed, you are attempting to induce a stall.  This behaviour is by design.  If you are very very gentle and the car is fuel injected, the ISV might eventually catch up and you may be able to move off without any throttle.

This is poor driving technique as you are effectively "lugging" the engine.  You'll experience the same type of effects as driving up a hill in too high a gear.  You should apply an amount of throttle before (and as) you release the clutch.

Comment: Ok thanks, as you saying it will dissapear over time?

Comment: @Teo I'm sorry, but you're not understanding what's being said to you; this is clear from your repeated "It will go away in time, won't it?" comments. motosubatsu and Steve both observe that letting the clutch out without adding throttle is a poor driving technique; adding some throttle as you release the clutch is what you want to do. They are exactly correct. The vibration may ease after time, but it (the vibration) is bad for the machinery and unless you change your clutch-and-throttle technique, things will not improve.

Comment: @David No you are not understanding my point, you all say about poor driving technique,,i understand that and i never release clutch when driving without adding throttle,,but it is not normal for the car to vibrate in first gear without adding throttle,,its a problem here and this is what im trying to understand form your answers!

Comment: It is normal for a car with a healthy clutch to vibrate or ever stall when the clutch is released without any throttle applied.

Comment: @SteveMatthews Yes and as you saying it is supposed that the vibration will dissapear over time when the clutch will not be as healthy as it is now?

Comment: Once the clutch is worn it will begin to slip a little which will damp the severity of the bite point.